# Azure storage account cannot map drive locally with DNS

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have created a storage account and a fileshare on Azure, but my ISP blocks port 445, bummer!

So I went ahead and created a virtual network, then a virtual gateway, then a VPN, then a private endpoint where there is an entry like this:

NAME   mystorageacc  (not the real one)
VALUE    10.0.0.4

I can map the network drive using the  10.0.0.4 IP address while connected to the VPN, but I don't want to use that, I would like to use the new DNS, but when I ping mystorageacc.file.core.windows.net I still get the public IP address 52.239.193.168 instead of the private from my virtual network 10.0.0.4.

How do I achieve this? using mystorageacc.privatelink.file.core.windows.net still points to the public IP address, so what resolves to 10.0.0.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the easy way for test is to edit `hosts` file in the directory `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` on the local VPN client machine.

Add the following record in the HOSTS file.

```
10.0.0.4  mystorageacc.file.core.windows.net
```

Another solution is to use a DNS forwarder. You can add Azure DNS (`168.63.129.16`) as a forwarder on your custom DNS. Read this document [On-premises workloads using a DNS forwarder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#on-premises-workloads-using-a-dns-forwarder) for more details. For more steps, you could refer to step 5 in [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/azure-sql-db-private-link-private-endpoint-connectivity/ba-p/1235573).